# How to avoid Chrome caching temporary down API's?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

I have an AngularJS application running on www.domain.com. Sometimes one of our api.domain.com will be down. If somebody on Chrome (only of Chrome so far) goes to one page to should load JSON data from this API, and the API is down, Chrome might cache that the API is down for a while (up to days?). When we ask people to clear their cache it's working again.
Is there a way to prevent that? I don't want Chrome to flag that a request is not working and doesn't try again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case simple `timestamp` at the end of query would bust any cache:

Is cached:

```
GET http://exmaple.com/api/data
```

Each time you append new timestamp and it will bust the cache:

```
GET http://exmaple.com/api/data?12343455345345
```